# ERROR CODE #1111 FOR SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT ROLE.PersonID
FROM ROLE
WHERE COUNT(ROLE.PersonID) > 1
```

I am trying to get people whose `PersonID` appears more than once in that column. However, I am getting this error of invalid use of group function.

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` instead.

```
SELECT   ROLE.PersonID
FROM     ROLE
GROUP BY ROLE.PersonID
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```